# Shortcut to start gcloud machine on chrome book

Tags: gcloud, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm on a chrome book and would like to create a link to start a specific google cloud machine.

Is there a way to do this either with a web url, or another method?

Answer (score 1):

One lesser-known but very useful feature of Google Cloud Platform is [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/). The minimum requirement is a browser (✓). I'm a Googler and I use my old Pixel with Cloud Shell all the time. It works great.

Cloud Shell provides a browser-based shell running against a Compute Engine instance (VM) that comes bundled with the latest versions of Cloud SDK (aka `gcloud`) and Kubernetes CLI (`kubectl`). You may use this to run any `gcloud` (or `kubectl`) command.

To my knowledge, while Cloud Console surfaces much of the same functionality as `gcloud`, it is not possible to start/stop machines using it (or more specifically by crafting a URL that you may use to achieve this) because the functionality is behind buttons on the console page.

If you really want to do this via a URL, you can make a REST API call directly against the Compute Engine API. One way to easily construct this URL is to use Google's excellent [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer), navigate to the Compute Engine v1 API, find the `compute.instances.stop` method, plug in your values, authorize it (the tricky part doing this without API Explorer) and it should work. Then, you may copy the URL created for you by API Explorer to reuse. Something like:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[[YOUR-PROJECT]]/zones/[[YOUR-ZONE]]/instances/[[YOUR-INSTANCE]]/stop
```

Comment: Love cloud shell, but not quite what I'm looking for.  Definitely will look at the api explorer to see if it's possible there.  Was imagining I wouldn't be able to work with POST or PUT requests to do this with a click.

Comment: Maybe a small js/html file locally + the POST endpoint would do the trick.  Will try that.

Comment: There are two other workarounds: You can use an script with a curl -X POST and the API url as @DazWilkin explained instead of the js/html file once you solved the problem with the oauth or... You can visit this url and click in "execute" to let them do the authorization steps in your place: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/compute.instances.start/m/compute/v1/compute.instances.start?project=YOUR_PROJECT_NAME&zone=YOUR_VM_ZONE&instance=YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME&_h=2& and then the same link with compute.instances.stop to stop the instance.